# Route @Method annotation doesn't seem to get respected when matching routes

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing

I understand when allowing similarly accessible routes, that the order of the routes matter.

Where I'm confused is why when submitting a `DELETE` request to this route, does it match to the `GET` route, instead of ignoring it and trying the matched method one below it?

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{game}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function single(Request $request, GameSerializer $gameSerializer, Game $game) {
        $out = $gameSerializer->bind($game);
        return new JsonResponse($out);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{game}")
     * @Method({"DELETE"})
     */
    public function remove(Request $request, Game $game) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        $em->remove($game);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse([], 200);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

*Full disclosure*

I understand *why* it matches the top most route based on strictly patterns

I *dont* understand why the access method is getting ignored when doing so

So, just to test, I adjusted to move the `DELETE` based route up above the `GET` route

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{game}")
     * @Method({"DELETE"})
     */
    public function remove(Request $request, Game $game) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->remove($game);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse([], 200);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{game}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function single(Request $request, GameSerializer $gameSerializer, Game $game) {
        $out = $gameSerializer->bind($game);
        return new JsonResponse($out);
    }
```

only.. for this to happen when I tried getting an existing non-test record by performing a basic operation of visiting the url in a browser (so, `GET`)

[image]

and oh boy, did it ever delete that record.

Why is the Access Method being ignored?

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using ? And more importantly which version of SensioFrameworkExtraBundle ?

The @Method annotation from SensioFrameworkExtraBundle has been removed in latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, careful of which **SensioFrameworkExtraBundle** version you are using because the `@Method` annotation from **[SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)** has been **removed** in latest version. Instead, the Symfony @Route annotation defines a methods option to restrict the HTTP methods of the route:

```
*
* @Route("/show/{id}", methods={"GET","HEAD"})
*
```

But in your case, **if you're using HTML forms and HTTP methods other than GET and POST**, you'll need to include a _method parameter to fake the HTTP method.

[See How to Change the Action and Method of a Form for more information](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html).

Comment: ..... I'll have to check that, when did this happen? :X I admit it's been a few months since I've last created a fresh symfony project, but this thing didn't even give me a deprecation notification :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add route name and it must be unique.

Try with following way:

```
/**
     * @Route("/{game}",name="api_remove")
     * @Method({"DELETE"})
     */
    public function remove(Request $request, Game $game) {
      ...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{game}",name="single_remove")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function single(Request $request, GameSerializer $gameSerializer, Game $game) {
       ...
    }
```